# How to display all categories for all products in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm a beginner in MySQL and PHP and I need your help to get to know the solution. I would like to display a list of products and related categories. Products and categories are in the many-to-many relationship. Google solutions are very confusing to me. I will be very grateful for any advice.

My code displays duplicate products. Duplicated as many times as the category has. 
E.g:

```
Product1 - Category1;
Product1 - Category2;
Product1 - Category3;
Product2 - Category1;
Product3 - Category3;
```

index.php:

```
$result = $pdo -> query('
SELECT product.id, 
       product.name AS product_name, 
       seller.name AS seller_name, 
       category.name AS category_name
  FROM product
  LEFT JOIN seller ON product.sellerid = seller.id
  LEFT JOIN product_category ON product.id = product_category.productid
  LEFT JOIN category ON product_category.categoryid = category.id
');

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $products[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'], 
        'product_name' => $row['product_name'],
        'seller_name' => $row['seller_name'],
        'category_name' => $row['category_name']
    );
}
```

index.html.php:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
    <li>
        <span><?php htmlout($product['id']); ?></span>
        <span><?php htmlout($product['product_name']); ?></span>
        <span><?php htmlout($product['seller_name']); ?></span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span><?php htmlout($product['category_name']); ?></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

How to display all categories for each product? What should the loops look like? I would like to achieve:

```
Product1 - Category1, Category2, Category3;
Product2 - Category1;
Product3 - Category3;
```

Comment: FYI, you can just write `$products[] = $row`, since you're not changing any of the keys.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would only show one category for each product. Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Or just `$products = $result->fetchAll();`

Comment: My code is more extensive and the keys are changed. I changed some elements of the code to make it more readable in the forum. But thank you, I did not know about it!

Comment: Oh, my mistake. The result shows duplicate products as many times as there are categories. I will change this in the question immediately.
E.g:
Product1 - Category1; 
Product1 - Category2; 
Product1 - Category3; 
Product2 - Category1; 
Product3 - Category2;
And it should:
Product1 - Category1, Category2, Category3;
Product2 - Category1;
Product3 - Category2;

Comment: You're creating a cross product between all the sellers and categories.

Comment: They're not duplicates, since they have different seller names in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get all the sellers and categories in each row.

```
SELECT product.id, product.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT seller.name) AS sellers,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category.name) AS categories
  FROM product
  LEFT 
  JOIN seller 
    ON product.sellerid = seller.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN product_category 
    ON product.id = product_category.productid
  LEFT
  JOIN category 
    ON product_category.categoryid = category.id
GROUP BY product.id
```

Comment: OMG! It works! I would never find an answer without your help! Thank you very much!